# Why AlertDialog displays blank message?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm developing a simple game. I'm using SQLite to save data and I am trying to display the data in an AlertDialog popup. It seems that the text is being placed where it should be, but it's not showing. There's a blank space where the text should be. 
These are the methods I use to make the AlertDialog and add text to it:

```
public void viewAll() {

    allGames.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                //show message
                showMessage("Error", "No data found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("Name : " + res.getString(0)+ "\n");
                buffer.append("Tries : " + res.getString(1)+ "\n");
                buffer.append("Difficulty : " + res.getString(2)+ "\n\n");
            }
            showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void showMessage(String title, String Message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
```

Before the database was populated, and before the text was added to the Alert Dialog

[image]

After text was added to it

[image]

As you can see, the AlertDialog gets bigger when I add text to it. Please let me know if you see any error in my code or is you want to see more of it.

Comment: Do you have other alert dialogs in your app? If then does it work properly? There's a chance your alert dialog message text color could be white and that causes it not to be seen.

Comment: please post your style.xml

Comment: I don't have any other alert dialogs in my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below answer which will work in all version:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
else
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setMessage(Message);
builder.create().show();
```

Comment: Huh, now its working but now there's a blank space over the title.

Comment: Try `MainActivity.this`(means Activity.this), instead of `this`. Because I have seen that sometimes result have changed due to context value getting by different method.